# Unable to run application after installing on phone

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

When I clicked run, the apk used to auto start up on my phone before, but now it just remains unchanged on the developer option,

once i click run on eclipse, it shows the following on the console:

```
[2014-03-11 16:26:36 - MyFirstApp] ------------------------------
[2014-03-11 16:26:36 - MyFirstApp] Android Launch!
[2014-03-11 16:26:36 - MyFirstApp] adb is running normally.
[2014-03-11 16:26:36 - MyFirstApp] No Launcher activity found!
[2014-03-11 16:26:36 - MyFirstApp] The launch will only sync the application package on     
[2014-03-11 16:26:36 - MyFirstApp] Performing sync
[2014-03-11 16:26:36 - MyFirstApp] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device             
[2014-03-11 16:26:38 - MyFirstApp] Uploading MyFirstApp.apk onto device 'EP73226B61'
[2014-03-11 16:26:38 - MyFirstApp] Installing MyFirstApp.apk...
[2014-03-11 16:26:41 - MyFirstApp] Success!
[2014-03-11 16:26:41 - MyFirstApp] \MyFirstApp\bin\MyFirstApp.apk installed on device
[2014-03-11 16:26:41 - MyFirstApp] Done!
```

But as i said nothing come up on my phone, 
then I try other method like putting the apk into my download file and installed it , it says, `Do you want to install an update to this existing application? Your existing data will not be lost. it does not require any special access.`  once i click on install, it shows application installed and leaving my two button, Done and Open. But the "open" button is non-clickable

Is wired, I can't find it neither in internal storage and SD card, not even in my install app list.

My setting 
USB debugging is clicked
stay awaked is clicked

This is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0"   encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myfirstapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.Display1MessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display1_message"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

my android version is 4.3 is sony ZR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.   It should contain something like this:

```
<application details omitted>
    <activity  details omitted>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

If you don't have an intent filter like the one shown above, Android does not know which activity to start to launch your application.

Comment: I just update my post with my manifest on, it seems nothing wrong with it, may u give it a look please

Comment: The intent filter needs to be inside the activity element.  You have it appearing before the activity element.

Comment: Yup, seems ok, but there is other issue come up, 
it said **unfortunately, MyFirstApp has stopped **once i launch

Comment: And also my app name suppose to be MyFirstApp, but the app name shows on my phone is call **my message** does it relate?
And can u advise my why my app name is wrong please?

Comment: OK.  One problem solved.  You have several more problems in your manifest.   I suggest you generate a new Hello World application and compare the automatically generated manifest to the manifest you are using in this application.   Make your manifest look as much like the hello world manifest as possible (Class names may be different. Everything else can be the same)  Be sure you understand the reasons for any remaining differences.  If you don't understand, read about the manifest file.  If that doesn't help, ask a new question on StackOverflow (after you have done your research.)